# Allow a custom python class to add in both directions

Tags: python, class, overriding, addition

I have created a custom class that I want to be able to handle addition in both ways. As of now it only works if I have the class on the right hand side and the thing to add on the left (i.e. class+variable). How do I change the code below to include addition in the opposite direction (i.e. the other variable+class).

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.offset + other
```

Comment: numpy objects also have a `__array_prioity__` attribute, which helps control behavior with `numpy scalars` (e.g. `np.array(1)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) special function:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return self.offset + other
```

This function will be called if the left operand does not support the addition operation and the operands are of different types.